# How to create a model class for dynamic keys and values in firebase database in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

How to retrieve all the key nodes and values inside a model class?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNFRS.jpg) is my database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create a model class for dynamic keys?

There's no way you can do that. You **cannot** have dynamic variable names inside a class. The name of the fields that exist in a class should match the ones the exist in the database. However, there is a way in which you can read dynamic data and that would be:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("MyData").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey();
                String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", key + "/" + value);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

This will work assuming that "S71M ... b7z1" is the UID of the authenticated user. If it's not, you have to hardcode that value inside the second `.child("S71M ... b7z1")` call.

The above code will produce the following result in the logcat:

```
3/10
13/60
...
```

Also, remember that you need to have the same type of data for all the values. As I see in your schema, you don't have. Some are strings and others are numbers:

[image]

So try to change all values to String, and the code may remain unchanged or, change all values to be numbers and the use:

```
long value = ds.getValue(Long.class);
```

In case of keys, there is nothing you should do, as all keys are strings.

Comment: then how to retrive this data on reyclerview according to their respective user

Comment: It sounds like your question started off about "how to create a model class for dynamic keys and values", but now you are asking how to display the data in a RecyclerView. Here is an example of a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849). At this point, I recommend you make your own attempt to achieve that, and ask another question if something else comes up. In this way, I or other Firebase developers will be able to help you.